# Calculate power in the parallel circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

How to calculate power in the parallel circuit. What is the equation?

Data:
R1 = 15 Ohm
R2 = 19 Ohm
R3 = 16 Ohm
U (tension) = 84 V

Comment: Which parallel circuit? If you can add a circuit diagram that would be helpful, even if it is trivial. Also what do you mean by tension? Are you asking the power in whole circuit or power consumed by individual resistor?

Answer (score 1):

Because of the rules around homework I will not give you the final solution, only the roadmap to it. Assuming all resistances are parallel (if this isn't the case, edit your question) we have the following equality: $$\frac{1}{R_{equivalent}} = \frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2} + \frac{1}{R_3}$$

Tension is probably a literal translation of the word for potential difference in your language (it is in mine) so I will treat it as that. We can use the formula for power in the circuit: $$P = \frac{U^2}{R_{equiv.}}$$

With these formulas you should be able to reach the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If they are all in parallel, you can calculate the current (U/R) and then the power in each resistor.